# Angular 4.x: How to load chance.js in ngOnInit()?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in angular 4.x I want to load change.js in ngOnInit() function. How can I do this I have tried few thing but none worked:

here is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

...
.....
    declare var chance: any;

    import 'src/assets/js/chance.js';
    ....
    ....
    export class ComposantComponent implements OnInit {
    ....
    ....
          ngOnInit() {
            this.http.get("src/app/datas/data.json")
              .subscribe((data)=> {
                setTimeout(()=> {
                  this.data = data.json();
                  this.data.forEach(function(row, index) {
                    row.checked = false;
                     // use chance here ... 
                  });

                  console.log(this.data[0]);
                  // console.log(chance);

                }, 500);
              });
          }
    ....
    ....
    ....
    }
```

Can you please help ?

Comment: You've tagged javascript and angular, yet your code looks like typescript and your header says angularjs not angular? Very confusing and possibly won't get the people you need looking at this. Note that their is a significant difference between angularjs and angular.

Answer (score 3):

finally found a solution.

In index.html

```html
  <script src="http://chancejs.com/chance.min.js"></script>
```

in my `component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var Chance: any; // for externals librairies
```

In my class:

```
  chance: any;
  constructor(){
    this.chance  = new Chance();
    console.log(this.chance.ip());
  }
```

fill free to improve this solution ...